# How to get android signing certificate back from jenkins plugin

Tags: android, jenkins, signing

I have the jenkins project for android app. Apk signing with jenkins plugin(see pic below):

[jenkins sertificate settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWsGT.png)

HOW can I get back my .p12 certificate file from jenkins?

Comment: what does the interrogation point says for the certification option ?

Comment: the poin says that sertificate was uploaded to the plugin as a file, but now I didn't know how to get it back because I haven't path or other way to access to it

Comment: have you checked in the jenkins plugin folder on the jenkins server ?

Comment: nothing in folder(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, identify correct Jenkins home directory. Go to "Manage Jenkins" and then "System Information". Find a value of `JENKINS_HOME`.

Next, log in to Jenkins via SSH and go to that directory. A file named `credentials.xml` will contain your secrets.

Find the ID of you certificate (e.g. in the URL):

[image: Credentials ID in URL]

Finally, fire up a scripting console of your Jenkins instance (available at `/script` URL or via "Manage Jenkins" -> "Script Console") and execute this script:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*
import hudson.security.*
import java.security.*
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

def creds =  CredentialsMatchers
                .firstOrNull(
                        CredentialsProvider
                            .lookupCredentials(
                                Credentials.class,
                                Jenkins.getActiveInstance(),
                                ACL.SYSTEM,
                                Collections.emptyList()
                            ),
                        CredentialsMatchers.withId("9X9X99XX-XX9X-9X99-9X9X-9X9X9999XXX9")
                )

// This will print a decrypted password
def password = creds.password
println password

// This will print all the available aliases
creds.keyStore.aliases().each { println it }

// Imagine, the alias you need is myapp.
// Get JVM representation of you certificate and key
def cert = creds.keyStore.getEntry("myapp", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray())).certificate
def privKey = creds.keyStore.getEntry("myapp", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password.toCharArray())).privateKey

// Format certificate and key
certpem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
        DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cert.encoded) +
        "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
keypem  = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n" +
        DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(privKey.encoded) +
        "\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

// Print them
println certpem
println keypem
```

BTW, you can find your encoded credentials by ID in `credentials.xml` in Jenins home. It should look like:

```
<com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl>
    <scope>GLOBAL</scope>
    <id>9X9X99XX-XX9X-9X99-9X9X-9X9X9999XXX9</id>
    <description>App signing certificate</description>
    <keyStoreSource class="com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl$UploadedKeyStoreSource">
        <uploadedKeystoreBytes>{ENCRYPTED_CERTIFICATE}</uploadedKeystoreBytes>
    </keyStoreSource>
    <password>{ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD}</password>
</com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.CertificateCredentialsImpl>
```